# urllib2 geturl() does not work for some url redirects

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am learning python and trying to get the urllib2 geturl() to work. So far, I have the following skeleton, which looks like:

```
import urllib2
gh=urllib2.urlopen(http://somewebsite.com/).geturl()
print gh
```

which seems to work fine. However, when I try for example using a url given [here](http://pastebin.com/YQPH1yP9), it fails to get me the "final url" (but works on a browser).

I would appreciate any guidance to solve this.

Comment: @dm03514: that does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens, because you are redirected using javascript, and `urllib2` can't handle javascript. If it is important to handle javascript redirects, use [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the clarification. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: @JamesW -- I think selenium is your best bet, sometimes it would be possible to extract the url from the script, but as it isn't even uniform in this case, I think it would be too big of a hassle.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply! I have accepted your answer now.